# show that $HK = ⟨H \cup K⟩$

Tags: group-theory

If G is a group and $H, K \leq G$ and if H and K commute then $HK =  ⟨H \cup K⟩$

It would be intuitive that $HK = ⟨⟨H⟩ \cup ⟨K⟩⟩$ but I don't know how to show the equality above.

**Attempt to proof**

$⟨H⟩ =\{ x_1^{\epsilon_1}....x_n^{\epsilon_n}, x_i \in H, \epsilon_i \in \{±1\}\}$

$⟨K⟩ =\{ y_1^{\epsilon_1}....x_m^{\epsilon_m}, y_i \in K, \epsilon_i \in \{±1\}\}$

Now I don't know how to construct $⟨HK⟩$

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious that $\langle H \rangle =H$ and $\langle K \rangle =K$?

Comment: You need to show that $\langle H \cup K \rangle \subseteq HK$ (very easy) and $HK \subseteq \langle H \cup K \rangle$.

Comment: When you say $H$ and $K$ commute, does that mean $hk = kh$ for $h \in H, k \in K$?

Comment: @arkeet Yes, by commutative I mean that. I think my problem is I don't understand what  the elements of $⟨H \cup K⟩$ are. I'd understand I it said $HK = ⟨HK⟩ =\{ x_1^{\epsilon_1}....x_n^{\epsilon_n}, x_i \in HK, \epsilon_i \in \{±1\}\}$

Comment: Well, trivially $\langle A \rangle = A$ for any subgroup $A$ of $G$, so the notation is superfluous there. The point is that $H \cup K$ may not be a subgroup, so $\langle H \cup K \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup that contains $H \cup K$. So the reason I say one direction is very easy is this: $HK$ is a subgroup, and $\langle H \cup K \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup that contains $H \cup K$, and obviously $HK$ contains $H \cup K$, so it must contain $\langle H \cup K \rangle$.